# Running a simple express app with ts-node-dev and get error: False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, package.json, ts-node

I am new to typescript and express. I am trying to run the simplest express app using `ts-node-dev`, but get the following error.

```bash
> ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev src/index.ts                                                 16:07:40
[INFO] 16:07:42 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.7.2)
Compilation error in /home/lht/microservice/ticketing/auth/src/index.ts
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lht/microservice/ticketing/auth/src/index.ts:1:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Module._compile (/home/lht/microservice/ticketing/auth/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-8101223397369532.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at require.extensions.(anonymous function) (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-8101223397369532.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/home/lht/microservice/ticketing/auth/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
[ERROR] 16:07:42 Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
```

The following is my `index.ts` file.

```js
import express from "express";
import { json } from "body-parser";

const app = express();
app.use(json());

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000!");
});
```

This is my `package.json` file

```json
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.35",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

I wonder if there are some configurations that I am doing are wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue for an angular project, after upgrading some dependencies. Same combination of `@types/node` and `typescript`, not using the others. Downgrading may help, that's my next move anyway

Comment: @beetstra Hi, I just changed the `ts-node-dev` version to `2.0.0-0` and the error disappears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [False expression: Non-string value passed to \`ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective\` in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488958/false-expression-non-string-value-passed-to-ts-resolvetypereferencedirective)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just change the `ts-node-dev` version from `1.1.8` to `2.0.0-0` in my `package.json` file, then run `npm install` again, and the error disappears.

```json
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.35",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0-0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me only after specifying the version of ts-node-dev in my start script in the npm package.json file, in the `"scripts"` object: `"start": "npx ts-node-dev@2.0.0-0 index.js"`

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this from a freshly built typeorm app (`npx create-express-typescript-application my-app -t typeorm`). Bumping `ts-node` to `^10.8.0` solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I observed, why other services are working fine, except one.
I found that, the failing service was getting compiled with different TS version.
After I changed TS version

```
"typescript": "^4.6.3"
```

to

```
"typescript": "4.6.4"
```

that also solved the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

A quick and easy fix is to run `npm install typescript@latest ts-node@latest`. The problem may be the old ts-node is incompatible with the latest typescript 4.7.x release and upgrade them fix my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem when trying to run a node server inside a yarn workspace with nodemon. Running nodemon from the workspace sub folder worked, but not from workspace root folder itself.

Script in worspace sub folder looks like this

```
"dev": "nodemon"
```

and from root folder

```
"dev:my-service": "yarn workspace my-service dev"
```

I solved it by specifically adding ts-node as a dev dependency to the "my-service" workspace

Answer (score 2):

just change the version of `ts-node`

to

```
    "ts-node": "10.8.1",
```

run `npm i` or `yarn`

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
npm uninstall ts-node && npm uninstall ts-node-dev
```

and then run:

```
npm i ts-node && npm i ts-node-dev --save-dev
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Only answer which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:
`ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only server.ts`

I used:
`ts-node-dev --respawn server.ts`
and it works.