# False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective` in typescript

Tags: typescript, ts-node, ts-node-dev

When I try to run ts-node-dev./index.ts, I get the below error, I updated my typescript and ts-node-dev, ts-node but this error keeps on popping if I remove dependencies that have @types/XXXX(eg:@types/express) it is working fine.

False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.

```
    "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^8.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.7",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql-utilities": "^1.1.3",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.22",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.20",
    "@types/node": "^15.6.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "mocha": "^9.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.3"
  },
```

Comment: I got this error when I had "ts-node" listed in my "devDependencies" but forgot to run "yarn install" / "npm install". 

Comment: Having the same error after updating typescript from 4.6 to 4.7 on a frontend Vue2 project . I don't have ts-node as a dependency.

Answer (score 173):

Upgrading to `"ts-node": "10.8.1"` solved the issue for me.

Comment: I experienced this issue on ts-node 9.1.1 and this fix worked

Comment: I switched TS from  `4.6.4` to `4.8.0-dev.20220618` and the error starts to occur. upgrading `ts-node` from `10.7.0` to `10.8.1` doesn't fix the error.

Comment: One of my dependencies used `ts-node` though I did not directly. I added `ts-node` as a dev dependency at `^10.9.1` and that fixed for me.

Comment: As this appears to be a bug in ts-node, can someone please post a link to an open bug with them, so we can track its progress?

Comment: I used `ts-node@9.1.1` in my personal project. In recent days, I faced the same issue, which is perfectly fixed by this solution.

Answer (score 83):

### Solution

My problem was caused by upgrading typescript from `4.6` to `^4.7`, and I did this to fix it:

```bash
# With NPM
npm install ts-node-dev@latest ts-node@latest

# With yarn
yarn upgrade ts-node-dev@latest ts-node@latest

# With pnpm
pnpm up ts-node-dev@latest ts-node@latest
```

I was using `"ts-node": "^10.7.0"`, and `"ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8"`, after upgrading both dev-deps, the issue was solved.

### Why

TS 4.7 upgrades the [resolution mode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#resolution-mode) (see the last line). Given that the `ts-node` and `ts-node-dev` are using the old resolution mode internally, updating them to the later version, to be exact `ts-node@>=10.8.0` and `ts-node-dev@>=2`, fixes this problem.

This chapter is added for @KhachaturStepanyan

### TL;DR

After upgrading only "ts-node"(from Houssem Hichri's answer), the error remained, because I was using `"ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8"`.

Comment: This also works for TS `4.6` to `4.7`

Comment: Awesome, this fixed it

Comment: Upgrading ts-node didn't fix my issue. I have to downgrade from 4.7.4 to 4.6.4

Comment: This solved for me using npm.

Comment: I don't know what was the cause but this also fixed my problem, thank you!

Comment: @KhachaturStepanyan I added a "Why" chapter for you.

Answer (score 24):

I was upgrading typescript to `4.7.4` and I fixed this by upgrading `ts-loader` to `9.3.1`.

Comment: which requires me to update to webpack 5, which unfortunately causes a lot of other problems for the time being

Comment: I came here after upgrading to TS 4.9 (and react to v18) and this solution (after all the other upgrades mentioned in other answers) helped

Comment: Upgrading ts-loader to 8.4.0 was enough for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try downgrading to typescript@4.6.x. This may be needed if this issue occurs without `ts-node` installed.

Answer (score 4):

If none of the above issues works for you....

Do try updating ts-loader also....

The command is: `npm install ts-loader@latest`

Answer (score 3):

`yarn add -D ts-node` or `npm install --save-dev ts-node` solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I replaced ts-loader with babel-loader in **webpack** configs

*before:*

```
{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "ts-loader"
                },
            ],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/, 
        },
```

*after:*

```
{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                },
            ],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/, 
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

Using typeorm 0.2.43 & typescript 4.9.5

Problem fixed on my code upgrading ts-node to 10.9.1 (lastest version by now)

```
npm install ts-node@latest -D
```

Answer (score 1):

probably it's a node versioning error, so try to update your node version and check package.json file

Comment: Thanks!  I had the error on Node.js version 14, but not when I upgraded to 18.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following versions worked for me.

`ts-node 10.8.1`  & `node 14.17.3`

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I had an out of date global version of ts-node that was causing issues, even though the one in the local project was fine. I resolved it by uninstalling the global version and using the npx version.

> npm uninstall -g ts-node
>
> npx ts-node app.ts

Answer (score 1):

Since no one mentioned it, I was upgrading versions of a package, and somewhere between upgrading and building this error popped up. I couldn't figure out if the previous answers were useful, so I just nuked `rm package-lock.json` after verifying that my `package.json` has the dependencies I want. After building again with a new `package-lock.json`, my project succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

updating ts-loader and ts-node to latest , resolved in my case

```bash
npm install -D ts-loader@latest ts-node@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a TS error. Upgrading to the latest version is the recommended path.

However, in my app moving to the latest version of TS did not provide significant advantages hence, I downgraded the TS to the version v4.2.4 from v4.9.5 to resolve the issue temporarily.

In case your situation is similar to mine (other high priorities) then delay TS upgrade strategy for time being if it is not posing quality issues.