# False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have the following error:

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js): Error:
> Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to
> `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package
> working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature.
> This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
> ...
> @ multi babel-polyfill react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index.tsx

At this point I've been trying everything:

- updating ts-node
- updating typescript
- updating ts-loader
- updating configuration of babel and webpack

And still, nothing seems to solve this issue.

At this point, I think it's not strictly related to the TS, but more likely with react-hot-loader configuration/usage, but I'm not sure. Here are my packages versions:

```
"react-hot-loader": "^4.5.3",
"ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
"ts-node": "^10.8.1",
"ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.7.4",
```

And webpack config for TS and react-hot-loader:

```
  module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', 'react-hot-loader/patch', './src/index.tsx'], 
  [...]
    module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
    use: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
```

If someone could give me some hints on what to look for now, or what can be wrong, I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [False expression: Non-string value passed to \`ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective\` in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488958/false-expression-non-string-value-passed-to-ts-resolvetypereferencedirective)

Comment: Having the same issue with my vue project. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Happened to me when I tried to update a `@types` package (`@types/three`). I have temporarily reverted back to an old archived DefinitelyTyped folder on my computer and that seems to resolve things for now until I can figure out what I need to update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I also tried almost all the things you did and for me was the solution to upgrade the latest version of chakraUI to `2.2.1`. If you are using a UI library like chakra, maybe upgrading the version of that will help.

part of my package.json:

```
@chakra-ui/cli: ^2.2.1
ts-node: ^10.8.2,
ts-node-dev: ^2.0.0,
typescript: ^4.6.4
```