# Angular 13 - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed issue

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I upgraded my angular project from version 8 to 13.
After the completion of angular version 13, while running the application using 'ng serve' I'm facing issue like this

**`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated resolveTypeReferenceDirectives signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.`**

I tried most of the ways like updating or changing ts-node and typescript versions but still, I couldn't able to fix this.

Package.json:

[image: package.json]

Can you please help me to fix this or help me to understand why this issue is occurring.

Comment: Do any of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488958/false-expression-non-string-value-passed-to-ts-resolvetypereferencedirective

Comment: Or read this thread https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49257

Comment: Bojan, I have tried (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488958/false-expression-non-string-value-passed-to-ts-resolvetypereferencedirective) all ways. but nothing resolve my issue.

Comment: Bojan, most of the places mentioned need to update or change the ts-node. but i have tried all the ways.. Thank you so much your help.. but unfortunately it wont help my issue.

Comment: Bojan have your issue resolved and if yes how ?