# Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective` while updating Angular from 11 to 12

Tags: angular, package.json, angular-upgrade

I am updating Angular from 11 to 12 while following the documentation from [Update Angular 11 to 12](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-12.0).

This is my `package.json` file before updating.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-local": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "5.7.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "5.7.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.7.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
    "angular-google-charts": "^2.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-openapi-gen": "^0.15.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "cypress": "^9.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^6.0.0",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json after running command `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`

```
{
  "name": "web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-local": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.16",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "5.7.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "5.7.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.7.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
    "angular-google-charts": "^2.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-openapi-gen": "^0.15.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "cypress": "^9.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^6.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

But after running `npm install` followed by `ng serve`. I am having this error False expression: `Non-string value passed to ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated resolveTypeReferenceDirectives signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.` I tried restarting, invalidating cache, changing a lot of typescript versions but still no luck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72488958/5468463?

Comment: Changing ts-node did not work, tried also several versions of ts-node but no result

Comment: Did you install the packages? check typescript version also

Comment: Yeah. Installed packages also tried installing them with --legacy-peer-deps but no result.

Comment: Delete package.lock.json and /node_modules and re-install? Somewhere there is a dependency incoherence