# INTERNAL ERROR Debug Failure Typescript Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

In my react app I updated npm package to v4.7.2 and ran npm start , I have been getting this issue after

```
INTERNAL ERROR(undefined,undefined) Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
stack trace:
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
```

- I tried `npm install typescript@latest ts-node@latest` but this didn't work
- then I downgrade typescript from `4.7.4` to `4.4.0` , this also didn't work
- I deleted node modules and lock file and regenerated that also doesn't seem to work

Comment: Similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488958/false-expression-non-string-value-passed-to-ts-resolvetypereferencedirective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to sync versions of `ts-node` and `typescript`. Although I prefer using latest versions only, I ended up with these versions:

```
ts-node@8.10.2
typescript@4.3.4
```